# Setting Up own SVN Repository and updating on FTP

Tags: svn

I am developing a theme which constantly keep updating every month.

I work directly on the live site.

What I would like to do is set up an SVN repository such that I can keep all the revisions on my PC as well as when I save the file it is saved on the server.

Is something like this achievable?

Comment: What software do you use? Do you want to keep repository local or maybe use remote hosted service for it? Also this might be better asked on other site in the network (such as Stack Overflow) because it's not very specific to WordPress.

Comment: Hey rarst, Im open to anything that is free and yes I want to keep the repository on my local hard drive but each time I save, it should be on the FTP. Its like editing a file on FTP and saving revisions locally

Comment: I was a bit confused to post this here or at SO, is it possible to transfer this to SO?

Comment: I'd say it's a totally relevant WP.SE question; I did something similar and some steps are fairly wp-specific.

Answer (score 0):

I like to set up WP-core, the parent themes I use and my usual load-out of plugins as SVN externals, such that I just run `svn up` in a shell on the web-server, and it updates all code that isn't part of your own SVN. You can then just commit everything to SVN on your live development server, then run `svn up` locally to update your local copies of everything.

I've started doing this in the last few projects and find it's really helpful when moving towards more Agile-y workflows (or want to, say, integrate your SVN into Redmine).

This is a good tutorial:

http://log.pb30.com/post/565889524/install-wordpress-in-svn-using-svn-externals

Hope this helps!